# Lowering of higher order function with linear types

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions, linear-types

I've been experimenting with linear types recently, and have been wondering if the following transformation is possible. It's definitely not valid without linear types.

The aim is to lower the higher order function argument. This should be ok, because linear types ensure the HOF is called exactly once, so exactly 1 value of `a` exists. The issue is how to escape the lambda and observe `a`

```hs
   lower :: ((a %1-> b) %1-> r) %1-> b %1-> (r,a)
```

Comment: What happens when the first argument to `lower` is a linear `id` ?

Comment: That's a good question, and my first reaction was that it makes the above function impossible. Having thought about it a bit more, I'm not sure it does. At least, if r is then supplied with an a, the linear annotation on both a and b still hold

Comment: Followup: what about `lower :: (forall r. (a %1-> r) %1-> r) %1-> a`? It's almost but not quite double-negation elimination...

Comment: @DanielWagner, it looks plausible, and you might be able to go further: `blah :: ((a %1-> ()) %1-> ()) %1-> a` seems likely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: You cannot safely implement `lower`. As dfeuer and danidiaz say in comments: what if the first argument to lower is the identity function? With the implementation I showed in my old answer below you can write:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn (snd (lower (\x -> x) False))
```

Which will produce an error at run time:

```
Lin: Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries/base/GHC/Err.hs:74:14 in base:GHC.Err
  undefined, called at Lin.hs:25:19 in main:Main
```

So linear types do not give enough guarantees to make it safe to implement this function.

Edit2: You can save the situation by slightly changing the signature to: `lower :: ((a %1 -> b) %1 -> Ur r) %1 -> b %1 -> (Ur r, a)`. This way it is impossible to store the linear argument `a %1 -> b` in `r`.

```hs
import Control.Exception (evaluate)

-- from Data.Unrestricted.Linear from linear-base
data Ur a where
  Ur :: a -> Ur a

lower :: ((a %1 -> b) %1 -> Ur r) %1 -> b %1 -> (Ur r, a)
lower = toLinear2 lower'

lower' :: ((a %1 -> b) %1 -> Ur r) -> b -> (Ur r, a)
lower' f b = unsafePerformIO $ do
  ref <- newIORef undefined
  r <- evaluate $ f (toLinear (\a -> unsafePerformIO $ b <$ writeIORef ref a))
  a <- readIORef ref
  pure (r, a)
```

#### Old answer

This may not be the answer you are looking for, but if you know for sure that it is safe, then you can bend the rules a bit:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE LinearTypes, GADTs #-}
import System.IO.Unsafe
import Data.IORef
import Unsafe.Coerce
import Control.Exception (evaluate)

-- 'coerce', 'toLinear' and 'toLinear2' are also found in Unsafe.Linear from linear-base

coerce :: forall a b. a %1-> b
coerce a =
  case unsafeEqualityProof @a @b of
    UnsafeRefl -> a
{-# INLINE coerce #-}

toLinear :: (a %p-> b) %1-> (a %1-> b)
toLinear = coerce

toLinear2 :: (a %p-> b %q-> c) %1-> (a %1-> b %1-> c)
toLinear2 = coerce

lower :: ((a %1 -> b) %1 -> r) %1 -> b %1 -> (r, a)
lower = toLinear2 lower'

lower' :: ((a %1 -> b) %1 -> r) -> b -> (r, a)
lower' f b = unsafePerformIO $ do
  ref <- newIORef undefined
  r <- evaluate $ f (toLinear (\a -> unsafePerformIO $ b <$ writeIORef ref a))
  a <- readIORef ref
  pure (r, a)
```

I think the main purpose of linear types is only to get the extra type-level information, so I don't think there are any safe primitives that let you do this more cleanly (although I don't know all the ins and outs). Linear types do allow you to implement a safe interface with unsafe operations underneath. See for example how many times `toLinear` is used in [this file from linear-base](https://github.com/tweag/linear-base/blob/ead3a75d95f24eb68a552deb963fd49a74e7d0ec/src/Data/Array/Mutable/Unlifted/Linear.hs).

Perhaps the unsafe bits above can be outsourced to a lower-level library. Maybe something like [promises](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/promises), but then with linear types.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it might come to performunsafeio. I had approached it, unsuccessful so far, with additional restrictions on the types, using state monad. I did think it'd yield to that, with the right restrictions

Comment: I don't know much about linear types, but what if the first argument to `lower` *stores* its argument in its result rather than actually *calling* it? Then if the `a` component of the result is used first, you'll get undefined.

Comment: @dfeuer you're right. I just tested that. It turns out that this is not safe.

Comment: I don't think the counter example using and is a valid one. Linear types as far as I understand only guarantee the multiplicity if the output is consumed linearly.

Comment: @OllieB I've added a second edit to show a slight change you can make to make it (hopefully) safe again.

Comment: That's a nice idea.

Comment: Ooh, that fix looks clever!